# Using string erase() and string length() to delete certain chars from a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, for-loop, erase

I've written a function below to traverse a string a delete all spaces `' '` and `'-'`s. However, it is skipping some elements of the string and leaving `'-'` at the end so the logic must be incorrect. Could anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string FormatString(string S) { 

    size_t original_size = S.length();

    cout << "Length at start is " << S.length() << "\n";

    /*Count spaces and dashes*/
    for(size_t i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {

        cout << "Current letter is " << S[i] << "\n";

        if((S[i] == ' ') || (S[i] == '-')) {
            cout << "Deleting current letter " << S[i] << "\n";
            S.erase (i,1);
            cout << "Length is now " << S.length() << "\n";

        }
    }

    std::cout << S << '\n';

    return S;
}


int main() {

    std::string testString("AA BB-4499--5");
    std::string result = FormatString(testString);
    cout << result << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Length at start is 13
Current letter is A
Current letter is A
Current letter is  
Deleting current letter  
Length is now 12
Current letter is B
Current letter is -
Deleting current letter -
Length is now 11
Current letter is 4
Current letter is 9
Current letter is 9
Current letter is -
Deleting current letter -
Length is now 10
Current letter is 5
AABB4499-5
AABB4499-5
```

Comment: [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: Using `std::remove_if` is not possible I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because you increment the position after an erase.

When you do an erase you move all the other characters down one. If you then also increment your position in the string you effectively skip a character.

If we start with this:

```
"AA BB-4499--5"
```

After deleting a few character we are left with this

```
"AABB4499--5"
         ^           // i is 9.
```

You now delete the character above the cursor.

```
"AABB4499-5"
         ^           // i is 9.
```

Now you start the next iteration of the loop.

```
"AABB4499-5"
          ^          // i is 10.
```

You notice that you skipped over a character.

A better implementation of this algorithm is:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < S.length();) {     // Notice no increment here
    if((S[i] == ' ') || (S[i] == '-')) {
        S.erase (i,1);
    }
    else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

We can improve on this with iterators:

```
for(auto loop = std::begin(S); loop != std::end(S);) {
    if (*loop == ' ' || *loop == '-') {
        loop = S.erase(loop);
    }
    else {
        ++loop;
    }
}
```

Now that we are using iterators we can loop at standard algorithms

```
auto newEnd = std::remove_if(std::begin(S), std::end(S),
                             [](char c){return c == ' ' || c == '-';});
std::erase(newEnd, std::end(S));
```

Comment: is there a particular version of C++ that this syntax is valid for or is just for illustration purposes? I have changed it to this thanks `auto newEnd = remove_if(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c){return c == ' ' || c == '-';});
 S.erase(newEnd, S.end());`

Comment: @samsunggather This is C++11 syntax. I prefer `std::begin(s)` over `s.begin()` as you can more easily generalize the types. The `std::begin(s)` will work for all standard containers but also for C-Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the function is that when a character is erased nevertheless the index is incremented. So some adjacent characters will be still in the string.

It is better to use the so-called idiom erase-remove which is based on the standard algorithms `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

std::string FormatString( const std::string &s, const std::string &erased = " -" )
{
    const char *data = erased.data();

    std::string t( s );

    t.erase( std::remove_if( t.begin(), t.end(), [=]( char c ) { return std::strchr( data, c ); } ), 
             t.end() );

    return t;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string testString( "AA BB-4499--5" );

    std::cout << FormatString( testString ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
AABB44995
```